# Socket programming in perl, problem with perlio layer?

Tags: perl, sockets, select

I'm noticing some problems with the perlio layer in perl.  Took me a good day to track it down and was hoping some other people knew something about this?  The scariest thing about this is that since its so low-level, I'm worried it'll reduce the code's portability.

Server code:

```
use strict;
use Socket;

socket(my $sock, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp')) or die();
setsockopt($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) or die();
bind($sock, pack_sockaddr_in(23457, inet_aton('0.0.0.0'))) or die();
listen($sock, 10) or die();

my $paddr = accept(my $csock, $sock);
if (not $paddr) { 
    die();
}
my ($port, $iaddr) = unpack_sockaddr_in($paddr);
printf "accepted %s:%s\n", inet_ntoa($iaddr), $port;
send($csock, "1234567890", 0);
recv($csock, my $tmp, 8192, 0);
close($csock);
close($sock);
```

Client code (that I change slightly to test):

```
use strict;
use Socket;
use PerlIO;

socket(my $sock, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp')) or die();
connect($sock, pack_sockaddr_in(23457, inet_aton('localhost'))) or die();
print "layers before = ".join(', ', PerlIO::get_layers($sock))."\n";
#binmode($sock, ':pop');  # uncomment this line to watch the code work...
print "layers after  = ".join(', ', PerlIO::get_layers($sock))."\n";

my $tmp;
print "1ret    = ".read($sock, $tmp, 1)."\n"; print "tmp $tmp\n"; stillpending($sock);
print "1ret    = ".read($sock, $tmp, 1)."\n"; print "tmp $tmp\n"; stillpending($sock);
print "1ret    = ".read($sock, $tmp, 1)."\n"; print "tmp $tmp\n"; stillpending($sock);
print "1ret    = ".read($sock, $tmp, 1)."\n"; print "tmp $tmp\n"; stillpending($sock);
print "8192ret = ".read($sock, $tmp, 8192)."\n"; print "tmp $tmp\n"; stillpending($sock);
send($sock, 'blah', 0);

close($sock);
```

Server output:

```
accepted 127.0.0.1:39944
```

Client output with binmode commented (perlio layer in use):

```
layers before = unix, perlio
layers after  = unix, perlio
1ret    = 1
tmp 1
no more
1ret    = 1
tmp 2
no more
1ret    = 1
tmp 3
no more
1ret    = 1
tmp 4
no more
```

Above blocks forever.

Client output with binmode uncommented (no perlio layer in use):

```
layers before = unix, perlio
layers after  = unix
1ret    = 1
tmp 1
still more
1ret    = 1
tmp 2
still more
1ret    = 1
tmp 3
still more
1ret    = 1
tmp 4
still more
8192ret = 6
tmp 567890
no more
```

My problem is that `select()` stop returning that data is pending when obviously (via strace) the first read() call has consumed the entire output sent by the server (into some internal buffer I imagine).  Upon which the last `read(..., 8192)` will also block when without the perlio layer, it does not block.

I guess I have the solution to my problem (pop the perlio layer), but I'm curious what other peoples thoughts are?  Is it a bug that `select()` reports `no more` data pending even though the first perl read (with perlio layer) has read everything into memory?

Has anyone else run into similar issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected: if you're using `select()`, you need to use `sysread()` instead of `read()`, because of the buffering (as you've discovered :).

From `perldoc -f select`:

> WARNING: One should not attempt to mix buffered I/O (like
>   "read" or ) with "select", except as permitted by POSIX,
>   and even then only on POSIX systems.  You have to use "sysread"
>   instead.

Comment: Ah, yikes... I've probably read that a hundred times, but forgot about that :-/  Thanks for pointing that out.